# IF in the Django template system

Tags: python, django, templates

How do I do this:

```
{% if thestring %}

    {% if thestring.find("1") >= 0 %}

    {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

I am assuming I need to build a template filter? Will that work?

Comment: Are you asking about the `>=` comparison?  Please update your question to clarify what your problem is.

Comment: Oops, I was checking if the word "1" appears in the string.

Comment: Please update the question.  Please don't add comments.  It's your question, please try to make it clear for others to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *need* to build a custom filter, though one would work -- the alternative of coding

```
{% if thestring %}

    {% if "1" in thestring %}

    {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

would also go just fine.

Comment: Relational and containment operators in `{% if %}` are only in the development version.

Comment: True -- it's only scheduled for release (as 1.2) in 3 weeks.

Answer (score 3):

It would. But use the `in` operator instead of the `find()` method.

Example:

```
{% if thestring|contains:"1" %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll find that the Django template system isn't designed to have complex logic in it.  This type of processing should happen in your view, then be passed to the template.