# Django template conditional delete button

Tags: django, django-templates

I've got a model called `Group` (not to confuse with the built-in Django groups) with a `ManyToMany` field called `admins` to `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. In my template I want the user to be able to delete a group when it is an admin (the admins field contains the current user). The way I am doing this at the moment is with a loop like this:

```
{% for admin in group.admins.all %}
    {% if user == admin %}<a href="/groups/delete/{{group.id}}/">[x]</a>{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Since Django discourages passing attributes to functions inside templates, I cannot use the `filter` or the `get` functions on the `admins` field. But I was wondering whether there was a more direct approach to solving this problem rather that looping through all admins.

Comment: Why dont you use the `is_superuser` boolean available in the django user model ?

Comment: Have you tried `{% if user in groups.admins.all %}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django templates [support the `if x in list` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276319/if-in-the-django-template-system) (since Django 1.2, according to the linked thread). You can simplify your for-loop with a single `if`:

```
{% if user in groups.admins %}
    <a href="/groups/delete/{{group.id}}/">[x]</a>
{% endif %}
```